# Deploy MERN Full Stack application on Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, mern, react-fullstack

I'm trying to setup an e-commerce store using MERN and currently have a Node backend that connects to a MongoDB database and serves some endpoints to return some results in JSON form. I then introduced a React frontend app which proxies back to `http://localhost:PORT`, receives the aforementioned JSON data and displays it. This works beautifully locally but that is because I'm basically running two npm commands using the `run-p` module (i.e. serving both the client and server using one terminal).

However, when I deploy to Heroku, all I get is a failed deployment ([Heroku build log](https://pastebin.com/Ash3WL8X))! My directory structure is as follows

```
root/
|__ .env
|__ package.json // Contains the start script ::"start": "cd react && npm run build && cd ../ && node server.js"::
|__ server.js // NodeJS file
|__ // ... some other files used by server.js
|__ react/
   |
   |__ package.json // Contains the default scripts created by npx create-react-app
   |__ build/
   |__ src/
   |__ public/
```

Would something like this even be possible in a single heroku deployment, or would I need to create two Heroku apps? All tutorials I've seen on deploying a full-stack application, tend to point towards the Node backend serving the static React build directory under `app.get('*', ...)`.

--- EDIT: 02-05-2023 ---

I have updated my `index.js` which hosts my BE server endpoints to basically use different endpoints than the React app. So any and all endpoints that are used by React, do not exist in the BE, and vice-versa.

For example:

Let's say my React app has these routes `/`, `/contact`, and `/help`. My NodeJS server would not serve any of these and let them fall under the `*` path to be served as a React static file. These work fine.

However, my NodeJS server is written to listen to some other endpoints, let's call them `/foo`, `/bar`, and when these are called via the React app, all I get are 404's ...

Anyone have any solution to this?

Comment: Amongst other things, the server wouldn't be running on localhost for any of the clients using the web application. Yes, if you want a single deployment the backend serves the compiler frontend. The dev server isn't designed for production use.

Comment: @jonrsharpe So you're saying that the `proxy` value should be the hostname that is being run in production and that should fix things?